# Fork system call output:

Tags: c, fork

Please explain the output for the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    if(fork()&&fork()){
        fork();
        printf("hello");
    }   
}
```

Output: hellohello

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand fork() returns twice, once to the parent and once to the child. The child gets returned `0` and the parent gets returned the `pid` of the child process. Knowing this, we can reason about the code:

Since in C, 0 is false, and Anything else is true the following happens:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
       //Create 2 new children, if both are non 0, we are the main thread
       //Jump into the if statement, the other 2 children don't jump in and go out of mains scope
    if(fork() && fork()){
        //Main thread forks another child, it starts executing right after the fork()
        fork();
        //Both main and the new child print "hello"
        printf("hello");
        //both main and child return out of if and go out of scope of main.
    }   
}
```

It should be noted once main executes the first `fork()` that child goes on to `fork()` a child of its own. But because of the `&&` operator that child gets `(0 && somepid)` which evaluates to false, which is why you do not get 3 hellos.